# RestKit different mime type for one response

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I would like to support different mime types for different responses. Most of the time the server returns json, but there are a few situations where it returns nothing and RestKit identifies these cases as plain/text mime types. Is there any solution?

Comment: Returns nothing? What do you want to do with the nothing?

Comment: The webservice returns with code 200 but empty body. It was created by somebody else. This is how I should work. The code 200 shows me that my request was successful.

Comment: If it's an empty body, Can't you ask the owner of the webservice to return a 204 ?

Comment: This would be the perfect solution, but I couldn't get this from the server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this exactly, but it works for me when using purely `AFNetworking` calls. Try setting the underlying `AFNetworking` HTTPClient:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].HTTPClient;
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"plain/text"]; // change default "Accept" header

// Put normal RestKit request code here       

[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"]; // change back
```

This should work, unless RestKit is overriding the default headers somewhere. (If your request is a GET, and you don't even need RestKit's Object Mapping functionality, I suggest using the `AFNetworking` methods with the default client and skipping the RestKit methods in that case.)

Comment: The RestKit overrides this setting, but for this special case I've modified the RestKit directly. Not a good solution, but I didn't find any better.